# jquery jasmine, fixtures not loaded

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I'm trying to load my fixtures in spec/category_keyword/categories.html. The content of the fixture is

My test

```
$(function() {

  beforeEach(function(){
     keywordsListView = new KeywordsListView({
       el: $("#keywords_list")
     })
  })

 it("should ...", function() {
    expect(keywordsListView.el.attr("id")).toEqual("keywords_list");
 })

})
```

However, keywordsListView.el is undefined which suggests to me that the fixture is somehow not loaded. I viewed the jasmine suite in firebug and didn't see anything related to fixture. I'm using the jasmine gem. Do I have to enable something?

Comment: As cool as the `el: ''myCoolJQuerySelector'` is, it makes it unnecessary hard to test the view. I always pass in the views element in the constructor so I can easily put a mock into my view when I'm test it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. keywordsListView.el is undefined either way.

Comment: In your test you can create a new DOM el and passed in into your view, or better just pass a mock, so you dont depend on the DOM while testing. Query the DOM in your view is an anti pattern like creating new instances in a class you wanna test. Sure this wasn't a direct answer to your concrete question but shows a way to not mess up with loading fixtures.

Comment: Are you using sinon.js and fakeServer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, I don't think the test has access to your keywordsListView variable. Declare the keywordsListView variable above the beforeEach function and populate it in the beforeEach as you currently have it.

```
$(function() {

  var keywordsListView;

  beforeEach(function(){
     keywordsListView = new KeywordsListView({
       el: $("#keywords_list")
     })
  })

 it("should ...", function() {
    expect(keywordsListView.el.attr("id")).toEqual("keywords_list");
 })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine itself doesn't include any fixture loading, the html reporter gives you a `div#jasmine_content` that jasmine will not touch and is yours to write html to if needed. If you need to be able to load more complicated fixtures, there are other plugins that will do that for you. The only one I've ever used is [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery). With this you can do something like:

```
$(function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
     loadFixtures('category_keyword/categories.html');
     keywordsListView = new KeywordsListView({
       el: $("#keywords_list")
     });
  });

  it("should ...", function() {
    expect(keywordsListView.el.attr("id")).toEqual("keywords_list");
  });
});
```

Note that jasmine-jquery expects your fixtures to be in `spec/javascripts/fixtures` unless otherwise configured by setting `jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = <something>`

The other thing you can do is let backbone create the element for you by not passing one in. Of course for this, your view will need to render itself instead of relying on whatever markup is generated by the server. This makes your view more self-contained as well.

Answer (score 0):

After loading your fixtures, you have to call your backbone functions / method without making spies on for your models.

And then you have find with your loaded HTML content.

Like:

```
loadFixtures("/path/to/fixtures.html");         
SpyOnObj.functionname();                        
expect($('body')).toHaveId("{ELEMENT_ID}");
```

I hope this will helps to you.